# Spring 3 Transaction support

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, transactions

Hi I am reading Spring in Action 3 book and I came across this paragraph where it talks about JPA transactions,

> It's important to note that the JpaDialect implementation must support
>   mixed JPA/JDBC access for this to work. All of Spring's
>   vendor-specific implementations of JpaDialect
>   (EclipseLinkJpaDialect, HibernateJpaDialect, OpenJpaDialect, and
>   TopLinkJpaDialect) provide support for mixing JPA with JDBC.
>   DefaultJpaDialect, however, does not.

My question is why would Hibernate or iBATIS would create a jpaDialect when we could directly use Hibernate instead of JPA. I am new to this and trying to understand the links between all these technologies, any help is really appreciated.

Thanks,
SS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because JPA is a specification, not an implementation, and some people prefer to *only* code to a specification. It's like programming to an interface, not an implementation.

(I've never *seen* a project change JPA implementations, but I'm sure it happens.)

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is an ORM (Object-relational mapping) and JPA is the Java Persistence API.

Simple description:

-Hibernate role is to map your database table to java objects.

-JPA role is to deal or offer methods to manage Transaction/persistence into that given database.

```
Hibernate provides an open source object-relational mapping framework for Java. Versions 3.2 and later provide an implementation for the Java Persistence API.
```

So if you use Hibernate 3.2+, it already implements the JPA spec so you don't need a third party JPA provider.